# Ckeditor Stripping all attributes, when re-editing content

Tags: wysiwyg

Ckeditor is stripping out all attributes from the source code.

This is the case I'm going through: 
When I add html code to the source of the Ckeditor, and then want to preview the changes by selecting source again, I find that no styling was taken. When I go back to check the source all styling attributes are removed and some HTML tags.

I found a way to save the content, without stripping by directly saving after pasting the html code in the source. But if I try to re-edit the content it strips all styling attributes and some html tags.

I am using Full HTML Text format, and did try previous versions of the ckeditor module. Also tried to modify the `config.js` file by adding "`config.allowedContent = true`;" as referred by the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div.)

```
<nav class="footer-wrapper"><section class="col-md-3">
<h3 class="block-title h5">
  About
</h3>
<ul class="list-unstyled"><li>
    <a href="/bio" title="">Biography</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/timeline" title="Plans and Billing">Timeline</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/quotes" target="_blank">Quotations</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/philo" target="_blank" title="">Philosophy</a>
  </li>
</ul></section>
```

CKeditor Stripped HTMl:

```
<p>About</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/bio" title="">Biography</a></li>
    <li><a href="/timeline" title="Plans and Billing">Timeline</a></li>
    <li><a href="/quotes" target="_blank">Quotations</a></li>
    <li><a href="/philo" target="_blank" title="">Philosophy</a></li>
</ul>
<p>Intellectual Legacy</p>
```

Any way to resolve the following?

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: Drupal 7.42 and latest ckeditor module and js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really hack the `config.js` file. You can pass any custom configuration values through the admin:

1. Go to `/admin/config/content/ckeditor`.
2. Click on the "Edit" link next to the profile you are working with.
3. Expand the "Advanced options" fieldset.
4. Enter the following code in the "Custom JavaScript configuration":

   ```
   // Instruct CKEditor to disable the filter. You can also limit this to specific tags.
   config.allowedContent = true;
   // Allow p, div, li and ul tags to have any attributes attached to them.
   config.extraAllowedContent = 'p(*)[*]{*};div(*)[*]{*};li(*)[*]{*};ul(*)[*]{*}';
   ```

See docs for [`CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent) and [`CKEDITOR.config.extraAllowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent). If you are insterested in having this in every Drupal installation, check out my [Drupal 7 installation profile](https://github.com/aramboyajyan/drupal7-profile).
The file in question is [here](https://github.com/aramboyajyan/drupal7-profile/blob/master/custom.install#L347).

Hope this helps.